# Add append to the URL inside echo

Tags: php, echo

I broke my head trying to solve the following case. I have the following PHP code and it works perfectly:

```
function add_text( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if( ! ( 'new_order' == $email->id ) ) return;
    echo '<p>'.__(' https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?OrderNumber=&Email=').$order->get_billing_email();'</p>';
}
```

The value of the `echo '<p>'.__(' https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?OrderNumber=&Email=').$order->get_billing_email();'</p>';` is (as an example):

https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?OrderNumber=&Email=emailaddress@gmail.com

All I want is to add the `&DateFrom=&DateTo` part after the email address inside the `echo '<p>'.__(' https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?OrderNumber=&Email=').$order->get_billing_email();'</p>';` part so the echo value should be like:

https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?OrderNumber=&Email=emailaddress@gmail.com&DateFrom=&DateTo

But I tried so many methods and didn't find a correct one.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: There's a syntax error in your perfect code: the `;` before the `'</p>';`. It should be a dot.

Comment: Sorry, was not intended as a sarcastic remark. I meant to say that you think the code is working perfectly, when in actually it isn't.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no worries, thanks

Comment: As an aside, why not use commas with `echo` instead of concatenation? That is, `echo a, b, c;` instead of `echo a.b.c;`

Answer (score 0):

A good way to build a query string is to use a PHP function for this:

```
$parameters = ['OrderNumber' => 1,
               'Email'       => $order->get_billing_email(),
               'DateFrom'    => '2020-01-10',
               'DateTo'      => '2020-01-20'];

echo 'https://app.demourl.com/Order/Query?'.http_build_query($parameters);
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php